# How to get rid of or remove spinners/arrows in react-select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select, react-select-search

I am using  from react-select but I am not able to remove spinners/arrows from the dropdown.

[image: The updown arrows marked in red]

I am able to remove the default separator | and Dropdown Indicator using

```js
<Select
  components={{
    IndicatorSeparator: () => null, DropdownIndicator: () => null
  }}
  {...}
/>
```

But how can I get rid of these arrows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're setting the `type=number` for the `input` element somewhere. In order to remove the up/down arrow. you can use the css code from [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_arrow_number.asp) tutorial.

You can also see all of the input types and how it's rendered out-of-the-box [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#%3Cinput%3E_types).

```css
/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Firefox */
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64341537/how-to-get-rid-of-or-remove-spinners-arrows-in-react-select]

Comment: Hi I am using react-select npm package and not sure how to apply this or override internal styles of Select dropdown.

Comment: @RohitSharma I'm not sure how you created the project but if you are using create-react-app, you can just create a css file and import it. I just added the live demo for you

Comment: Thanks a lot for the live example. This solved my issue.